# PHP Block randomisation

Tags: php

I'm looking for help implementing a customised randomisation in php. Randomisation needs to occur in blocks of 10 (for example) where if there are two outcomes, there will be 5 of each outcome in a random order. My issue is that the script I envision will only be outputting one of these outcomes at a time, which will happen when a webpage is opened.
Is this impossible? I have considered creating a text file containing an already randomised list that the code can read from, but in that case I still have to ensure that the outcomes are outputted one by one as needed.

Comment: I don't get it. Please elaborate. Example data and the expected result would be nice.

Comment: You'll never come up with a better home-brewed random number generator than the ones you already get with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it you want to randomise the order of a list of binary data with equal amounts of each value. Your problem seems to be that you don't know how to save the state of the engine that is reading these values one by one. You say that you have thought about using a text file to store the randomised list. You could use the text file to pop off a value at each load of the web page and save the file without that value. Once the file is empty your webpage can repopulate the file with a new block of values.